# Laravel SPA (laravel + vuejs + sanctum) deployed in subdomain returns wrong api

Tags: laravel, api, deployment, single-page-application, sanctum

I have this problem since several days.

I'm developing a Vuejs/laravel app, using Sanctum as an authenticator. where laravel mainly have the api gestion role, and I've started to deploying it. On Local, everything looks fine, api and auth are working.

On deploy, since my app is binded to be in a subdomain (laravelapp.maindomain with folder path of domain/laravelapp), when i try to access any page (vue-router) instead of domain/laravelapp/login i get domain/login, even if the page itself is looking fine.

If i try to reload the redirected page (domain/page) i have a 404. Also, since every API is pointing to domain/api/link instead of domain/laravelapp/api/link, everything is broken starting with auth.

I've tried modifying .env file, RouteServiceProvider, .htaccess(but i have no knowledge about that).

I also tried to set the subdomain Document Root to domain/laravelapp (it's the first thing i've done), but not only it dosn't work, if I try to print on screen subdomain's root, it returns domain. It's becoming a real issue right now, thank you for any help.

EDIT: I've discovered something. in the main domain there is a Joomla application. The api route contains the Joomla redirect (like, there is a plugin oh the site that changes language automatically, appending /en /it /de given the chosen language). So, in my case, the api is domain/index.php/en/subdomain. I tried again being more specific with document root, with no results, and playing around with .htaccess, but with no success.